# Git diff pattern

Tags: git, recursion, diff

I have 4 directories like so:

`root/
  |
  |
  |---dir1/ 
  |     |---file1.js 
  |     |---file2.js 
  |
  |---dir2/
  |     |---file3.js
  |
  |---dir3/
  |     |---dir4/
  |           |----file23.js`

I'm looking for a pattern to use like `git diff <pattern>` to display the diff of all those files in one command.
I've already tried `git diff path/to/root/**/*.js` but it's only displaying file1, file2 and file3.js.

Thanks!

EDIT:

To be more specific i'd like to have the diff of all my .js file located in the controllers directory. i've already tried `git diff path/to/root/controllers/**/*.js`

`root/
  |
  |---services/
  |
  |---controllers/
          |
          |
          |---dir1/ 
          |     |---controller1.js 
          |     |---controller2.js 
          |
          |---dir2/
                |---controller3.js
                |
                |---dir3/
                     |---dir4/
                           |----controller34.js`

Comment: Are you asking for a diff in between those files, or a diff in those files compared to stage?

Comment: @folkol i'm looking for a diff in those files compared to stage

Comment: See my answer, and ask there if something is not clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[git diff](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-diff)** will by default show the difference between the current file state and the **[staging area](http://git-scm.com/book/en/Getting-Started-Git-Basics)**, for all files in the repository.

```
[folkol@localhost (master)]$ git diff
diff --git a/dir1/file1.js b/dir1/file1.js
index 3be9c81..c82de6a 100644
--- a/dir1/file1.js
+++ b/dir1/file1.js
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 Line 1
+Line 2
diff --git a/dir1/file2.js b/dir1/file2.js
index 3be9c81..c82de6a 100644
--- a/dir1/file2.js
+++ b/dir1/file2.js
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 Line 1
+Line 2
diff --git a/dir2/file3.js b/dir2/file3.js
index 3be9c81..c82de6a 100644
--- a/dir2/file3.js
+++ b/dir2/file3.js
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 Line 1
+Line 2
diff --git a/dir3/dir4/file23.js b/dir3/dir4/file23.js
index 3be9c81..c82de6a 100644
--- a/dir3/dir4/file23.js
+++ b/dir3/dir4/file23.js
@@ -1 +1,2 @@
 Line 1
+Line 2
```

EDIT: If you are only interested in the .js-files, you can use this pattern:

```
git diff -- '*js'
```

EDIT again, due to updated question: If you want all .js files under controller:

```
git diff -- controllers/*js
```

Comment: Yeah you're right but in this case i will have the diff of the entire workspace which is not really handy. Even if a specify the .js files it won't be accurate enough. Actually i just want a recursive diff for a specific directory.